# Add some default text to Ctrl-Alt-F1 console to remind myself how to reboot properly

Tags: reboot, console, prompt

I do know there are questions and good answers, what to do if Ubuntu just hangs (like this one: [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)). My problem is that such a hang occurs so seldom for me, that I don't remember most of the answers at that time and I have no second machine to ask the Internet while my main system hangs.

I always remember how to open the console using some Ctrl-Alt-Fx combination. So is there a possibility to **have some lines of "intro text" in that console**, which tell me directly after switching to the console how to kill hanging processes and how to properly reboot? Think of it as a "reminder to self".

DOS had the ability to change the prompt in a console to arbitrary output. Maybe something similar can be done here to get me remember at least the basics?

Comment: Sticky note? XD

Comment: just kidding, man.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the text console, you'll see a line with a text like `Ubuntu 10.04 darkstar tty1` just before the login prompt. This message comes from the file `/etc/issue`, which you can customize to your wishes. The escape sequences are described in the `getty(1)` manual page.

Comment: Tested. Works fine. I'm still waiting for the next distribution update to see if my changes are replaced. If so, I might switch to the other solution.

Comment: 3 months later: I have successfully used the above system on two occasions now. Both times it helped avoid rebooting. Quite good, because I usually have several projects and documents opened at the same time and don't want to risk issues with them.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the 'message of the day' (motd). This is shown whenever you log in to one of the Ctrl-Alt-Fx terminals. You can edit it with this command: `sudo nano /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text`. This is a shell script that prints a help message to the screen. It is only part of the motd. The other 'fragments' can be found in the `/etc/update-motd.d` directory.